# Creating a hash automatically

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

I have an array ( array = ["home", "style", "honor", "home" ] and what I want to do is create a hash from this array like this :

```
hash = { "home" => 1, "style" => 2, "honor" => 3} #Array has two "home" element but I should give one value ("home" => 1) to both.
```

But I'm wondering is there any easy way to do this? Such as if i = 1 and "home" => 1 and then i will be 2, following "style" => 2. Should I use loops, enmerables ? Or is there better way?

Comment: "Should I use loops" – The answer to this question in Ruby is always No. There is pretty much never a reason to use loops.

Comment: What is the result going to be for `array = %w[home home style honor style honor home floor]`?

Comment: hash = {home => 1, style => 2, honor => 3, home =>4, floor => 5}

Comment: That's not possible. Keys must be unique.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your *desired output* is impossible. It doesn't matter what you try to use to produce it. It *cannot* be produced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing we need to do is remove the duplicate elements from the [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html). For that, we can use the [`Enumerable#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq) method:

```ruby
array.uniq
#=> ['home', 'style', 'honor']
```

Next, we need to pair up every element with its index. For that, we can use the [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) method, which gives us an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html) that `yield`s two-element arrays of the original element and its index:

```ruby
array.uniq.each_with_index
#=> #<Enumerator: ['home', 'style', 'honor']:each_with_index>
```

We can take a peek at what happens when we use the `Enumerator` by converting it to an `Array`:

```ruby
array.uniq.each_with_index.to_a
#=> [['home', 0], ['style', 1], ['honor', 2]]
```

The indices are off-by-one, but we could fix that using [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```ruby
array.uniq.each_with_index.map {|el, i| [el, i.succ] }
#=> [['home', 1], ['style', 2], ['honor', 3]]
```

Alternatively, we could fix it later, after we create the [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) by using the [`Hash#transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) method.

Another possibility is to convert the `Array` to an `Enumerator` first by using [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each) and then use the [`Enumerator#with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) method which takes an optional offset argument:

```ruby
array.uniq.each.with_index(1)
#=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ['home', 'style', 'honor']:each>:with_index(1)>

array.uniq.each.with_index(1).to_a
#=> [['home', 1], ['style', 2], ['honor', 3]]
```

In order to create the `Hash`, all we need to do, is use the [`Enumerable#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h) method to convert the two-element "pairs" we already have into key-value pairs. `Enumerable#to_h` also takes an optional block, which is another possible way for us to transform the indices.

```ruby
array.uniq.each.with_index(1).to_h
array.uniq.each_with_index.to_h {|el, i| [el, i.succ]}
array.uniq.each_with_index.to_h.transform_values(&:succ)
#=> { 'home' => 1, 'style' => 2, 'honor' => 3 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The desired hash can be obtained in a single pass, thereby avoiding the creation of temporary arrays.

```
array = ["home", "style", "honor", "home", "style", "hello"]
```

```
e = 1.step
array.each_with_object({}) { |x,h| h[x] = e.next unless h.key?(x) }
  #=> {"home"=>1, "style"=>2, "honor"=>3, "hello"=>4}
```

See the form of [Numeric#step](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step) that returns an enumerator. Key lookups (`h.key?(x)`) are very fast, the time required being almost independent of the size of the hash.

Comment: Seems like `h[x] ||= e.next` would be equally as efficient since `h` does not have a `default_value` and `e.next` will never be `nil`. Both `Hash#key?` and `Hash#[]` utilize the same function (`hash_stlike_lookup`) or we could go with a default `array.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = e.next}) {|x,h| h[x] }`

Comment: @engineersmnky, all good points. I especially like your `{ |x,h| h[x] }` because it is so very mysterious. For readability, I slightly prefer `h.key?(x)`.

Comment: if it is mystery you are looking for then `{_2[_1]}` (ruby >= 2.7.0 [Numbered block parameters](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.7.html#numbered-block-parameters)) or better yet `array.each.with_index(1).with_object({}) {_2.store *_1 unless _2.key?_1[0] }`

Comment: @engineersmnky, it appears you are are enjoying your Christmas eggnog. Note sure about better yet; isn't `_2` incrementing with every `_1`?

Comment: You are correct. It would require a `uniq` although it would be `_1[1]` that is incrementing with each `_1[0]` (`_2` would be the injected `Hash`)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner approach:

```rb
array
  .uniq
  .each_with_object({})
  .each_with_index { |(item, hash), index| 
      hash[item] = index + 1 
    }
```

Basically, I'm removing duplicates first, then iterating over the array (which is now essentially a set) with a hash and an index at hand, and just assign the next index to each item. I added 1 to each result just to match your desired outcome.